# Hopscotch Button Click Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Any ideas on why the following Hopscotch doesn't the following work?  We want a user to be able to click on a button to start the tour.
Many Thanks!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My First Hopscotch Tour</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hopscotch.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1 id="header">My First Hopscotch Tour</h1>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Content goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>

    <script>
      var tour = {
        id: "hello-hopscotch",
        steps: [
          {
            title: "My Header",
            content: "This is the header of my page.",
            target: "header",
            placement: "bottom"
          },
        ]
      };
      $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        hopscotch.startTour(tour);
      });
    </script>

    <script src="js/hopscotch.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Improved indentation in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add Jquery Script:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/hopscotch.js"></script>
```

*See Demo Here:* http://codepen.io/ihemant360/pen/OXmqXR

Answer (score 0):

You should include the jquery library in the head section of your file.

ie:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```